# cronで開始時間がバッティングする二つ以上のjobの実行順序制御

Tags: cron

job A: 3分に1回
job B: 10分に1回

とすると、毎時30分にA,Bの実行時間が被りますが、Bの実行中はAは待たなければならないという要件があります。毎時30分は、B,Aの順で実行してほしいのですが、そういったスケジュールの指定方法は可能でしょうか？

下記のような解決方法もあると思いますが、cronだけで解決できる方法がないかの質問になります。

1.
A,Bを一つのスクリプトにまとめる

2.
A,Bにファイルロック等の同期機構を設ける。

Comment: 確認ですが、crontab ファイルには `0/3 * * * * jobA`, `0/10 * * * * jobB` と書かれている、という事でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: はい。その通りです。

Comment: "cronだけで"の条件に当てはまるかわかりませんが、検索すると`flock`を利用した方策があるようです。実行順はcron table記述順([Linux(?)](https://askubuntu.com/a/143670/460420)では)のようなのでB->A順序も制御可能かと思われます。

Comment: 明示されていない複雑な条件が無いならば、@akira ejiri さんの回答で出来そうな感じですが。[シェルコマンド1行で複数コマンドや条件に応じた実行をする](https://qiita.com/wwwaltz/items/9ee247ee8fe3ab63fd27), [UNIX/Linuxの部屋 crontabコマンドの使い方](http://x68000.q-e-d.net/~68user/unix/pickup?crontab#prgmemo-crontab-multi-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

汎用性のある書き方ではありませんが、以下で実現できるはずです。

```
3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57 * * * * A
10,20,40,50 * * * * B
0,30 * * * * B;A
```

Bの処理時間によっては、Bの実行中にAが走り出します。
逆のパターンもあります。
1.や2.の方法を検討すべきと思います。
少し調べてみましたが、cronにジョブの同期を考慮した機能はありませんでした。

Answer (score 4):

前後をつけなくてはいけない要件が出てくると、ジョブスケジューラ(JP1/Job Center/Rundeck)を利用するのが一般的ではないかと思います。
簡単なものでは、Jenkinsもジョブの前後を付けられますし、時間投入など柔軟に対応可能です。ご呈示の同期機能は障害発生時に面倒になりそうで、可能な限り避けたいと。。。
♯同期機能持たせるぐらいならそれは１ジョブにまとめることを検討すべきとなるのでは？？